# Writing custom validators for Parsley in angular2

Tags: angular, parsley.js

I want to write a few of custom validators for `parsley` in my `angular2` `webapp`.

How can I do this in the best way?

I've experimented with writing them as directives and add them in the declarations array in the module in which I want to use them.

But since I want to use the same validators in a number of different modules, can I instead declare them in the `app.module.ts` instead?

It can also be a quite long list of directives in the declarations array when I have a lot of different custom validators, which is maybe a more aesthetic problem than anything else, but it's also something I would like to avoid if possible.

I also have the "import 'parsleyjs';" statement in each component. Can this also be moved somewhere else? Or will it not make sense to put them in a more general place, since they then will be included even where they won't be used?

I don't know how many validators I will end up with, but want to prepare for the case where it can be 10 or so.

Any ideas or hint on how I should best structure it all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, you could write a `ParsleyValidatorsModule` where you declare and export all your validators.

By exporting them, you can reuse them in other modules, just by importing the `ParsleyValidatorsModule`.

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [Validator1, Validator2],
exports: [Validator1, Validator2]
})
export class ParsleysValidatorModule{}


@NgModule({
  imports: [ParsleysValidatorModule] //you can now use your directives validators in all the components of this module
})
export class SomeOtherModule{}
```

Note that if you import the `ParsleysValidatorModule` in your `AppModule`, you will able to use the validators in all the components in this module, but not in the components of other modules. You have to import the module in each module that needs the validators.

Comment: Thanks. This way makes it a whole lot easier to keep everything in order.

Comment: Could you provide an example about how each `Validator1, Validator2` are?